# How I can make inputdialog() behave like input() on GUI?

Tags: vimscript, gvim

I use [dbext.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim) for any database related work so I have several connections configured on my `_vimrc` and when I need to switch between them I use the `DBPromptForBufferParameters` that this plugin provides.

As I'm using gVim this shows an popup window because it uses the [`inputdialog()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#inputdialog%28%29) function, however I want to this function behave like the [`input()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#input%28%29) function that does not show a popup.

There is some way to do this or I would have to change the plugin [source](https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim/blob/master/autoload/dbext.vim#L6510-L6525) ? I have looked at the documentation and source of the plugin and there isn`t any option to configure this.

Comment: Check the `:h guioptions` setting, adding `c` may do what you want (`set guioptions+=c`). If it works, `Enter` accepts, `Esc` cancels, `Backspace` deletes (if you have a default value and want to change it).

Comment: @VanLaser thanks, it is exactly what I want. I completely forgot to look at `guioptions`. Care to add as an answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `c` to the `guioptions` setting will replace simple GUI input popups with their console equivalents:

```
set guioptions+=c
```

If `inputdialog()` is called with a default value, `Backspace` first if you want to replace it.